# Dynamic web application in eclipse using MAVEN 3.04

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven, maven-3, m2eclipse

From past 90 hours I am trying to know how to use Maven in my web project, generate a war file and deploy it into my JBoss 4.2 Server.

I am not getting.
I am reading all kinds of blogs, googling almost all time, trying out all kinds of way to build a dynamic web project with maven, but trying out different methods make a simple thing more complex.

Few examples tell me how to run, few tell me to change the folder structure, few tell me transfer the contents of web content but nothing is matching my requirements. In some of the examples war file is getting generated, but of some big name, and it does not contain the jars inside. Uff.

I know maven is easy and makes our lives better but learning it for the first time makes it complex.

My requirement is simple.

```
1) Build a Dynamic web project in eclipse indigo. (Preferably in JAVA perspective )
2) Enable Maven dependencies, in eclipse.
3) Update pom.xml to add dependencies.
4) Finish the web application i want to do by writing classes, html pages, deployment descriptors.
5) Build the war file using maven "IN ECLIPSE ONLY". (the WAR file must have user specific name and not some name like "V1- Snapshot dash dash dash")
6) Deploy my war file in jboss 4.2 server deployment location. (Preferably  from eclipse )
7) Run my localhost server and my application from the browser.
```

And Done.

By spending time on it I am understanding how beautiful is maven, but I am not able to achieve what I want.

Please help me by giving me a detailed procedure on how to use maven to meet my requirements above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fist I would suggest to use the newest Eclipse (Juno) with Maven support (m2e and wtp-m2e).

The first step is to define your pom with the appropriate dependencies and the correct packaging type which is in your case **war**. 
If you really need a different naming you should leave Maven, cause maven makes assumptions about the naming of your artifacts which usually isn't a problem. The [default version patterns as 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/version-rules.html) etc.

If you wan't to deploy the war into JBoss there exist a number of possibilites to do such things and if you like to run your application locally it sounds you wan't to do some kind of testing ([integration testing](http://khmarbaise.github.com/maui/)) which is supported by Maven (see [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/)).

Furthermore you must learn if you like to use Maven to understand that not Eclipse is anymore the leader of the project configuration. This job has been moved to Maven or in other words into the pom file. If you like to use the project in Eclipse you need to import this project into Eclipse. 
Apart from the above i would suggest to go to a Maven training to lear all that stuff which is more effective than learning it yourself.

Comment: any appropriate link which has maven training to full-fill my requirement ?
where i get step by step procedure on how to do the above tasks.

(I have tried some zillion examples on google, nothing fits my criteria, please suggest me a link where i can easily figure out)

It will be a lot of help if you prepare a sample example of the above requirements, and write the steps in your blog with snapshots and share me the link.

Please blog on this. It will be of great help .

Comment: If you really like me to do your work i can do this. But than we are talking about consulting which costs money (you can contact me that way if you like). This platform is to support you in doing your work and where you have understanding problem but the job is yours and not for doing your work. I can recommend you to read the Sonatype Books (like http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/public-book.html, http://www.sonatype.com/Support/Books).